# JDBC ClassNotFound

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am making a web-app using GlassFish. In this webapp I need to be able to communicate with a MySQL Database. I downloaded the mysql-connector jar file and I added it in my build path. Still, when I try to connect to it I get this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

This is my code for connecting to the database:

```
public void connect(){
    try {
        Class.forName(dbClass);
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "333333");
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connected to Database");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also attached a screenshot so you can see that the jar is added to the buildpath:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: right click on the FinanceWorkServer, go to build path den on the pop-up go to library tab and select jar option and add the MySQL connector to your build path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jdbc driver `jar` is surely not exported to the server. Go to the `problems` view in `Eclipse` and you should see a warning that the `jar` is not exported. Right-click and select quick fix and then press OK to export it.

Comment: Thanks. that solved the problem. I will accept your answer as soon as it will let me :)

Comment: @Pazvanti - You are welcome:) Please also read the last paragraph from `JB Nizet's` answer. It is really important to use a connection pool. Otherwise your application will not be scalable.

Answer (score 3):

The build path is used to compile your app. At runtime, the container searches for libraries in the web app's WEB-INF/lib folder. Remove it from the build path, put it in this directory, and Eclipse will add it to the build path AND the runtime classpath automatically.

Note that, in a webapp running inside a Java EE container like glassfish, you normally put the JDBC driver in the Java EE container classpath, and configure the container to provide a datasource (encapsulating a connection pool) to the applications. Applications use their deployment descriptor and JNDI to get a reference to this datasource. Check the glassfish documentation. Opening and closing a connection at each request of a webapp is not something you should do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will definetly look into this as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Paste your mysql-connector jar to the lib folder of your container i.e. glassfish,

goto Installation directory of glassfish,

> Glasshfish_Directory\glassfish\lib

and paste your jar there, and restart the server

By placing your jar in lib folder of server, your jar file will be accessible to all the applications in your server. if Tomorrow you want to deploy another application, you dont have to worry about mysql-connect jar again.